# Where close with concat in case isn't working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a view. The following is giving me trouble. The first case works fine. The second for 217 doesn't work. I need to use CONCAT with a WHERE. I've tried a number of ways but can't get it to work.  Is there a syntax that will let me use a where with the concat that I'm using

```
(CASE  
    WHEN
      companies.mainSubcategory = '216'
    THEN
      CONCAT('{"label":"map","link":"https://www.google.com/maps?q=', 
             companies.street_number, ' ',
             companies.city , ' ',
             companies.state, '"}')
    WHEN 
       companies.mainSubcategory = '217'
    THEN
        CONCAT('{"label":"map","link":"https://www.google.com/maps?q=', 
               companies.street_number, ' ',
               companies.city , ' ',
                companies.state, '"}') WHERE
        companies.id = company_events.company_id)
   END) AS 'map1',
```

I do have joins but they only work when the mainSubcategory is 216. The schema is really quirky and isn't even close to being normalized. I'm not sure if the problem is the syntax when trying to add the WHERE above or if it is related to the fact that joins are in place.

```
INNER JOIN company_event_associated_companies ON 
  company_event_associated_companies.event_id = 
  company_events.id
  AND company_events.start_date >= CURRENT_DATE

INNER JOIN companies ON
  company_event_associated_companies.company_id = 
  companies.id
```

Comment: could you please post the complete query. i suspect a syntax issue may be the closing braces? shouldn't the `where` be outside the `end`?

Comment: What isn't working?  Is it a syntax error, or is the resulting JSON not what you expect?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? What do you mean by 'not working'?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `WHERE` statement in the middle of the `CASE` expression.  It doesn't belong.  I imagine that it should be part of an `ON` clause.

You should use table aliases.  The `CASE` should probably look like:

```
(CASE WHEN c.mainSubcategory = 216
      THEN CONCAT('{"label":"map","link":"https://www.google.com/maps?q=', 
                  c.street_number, ' ',
                  c.city, ' ',
                  c.state, '"}'
                 )
      WHEN c.mainSubcategory = 217
      THEN CONCAT('{"label":"map","link":"https://www.google.com/maps?q=', 
                  c.street_number, ' ',
                  c.city , ' ',
                  c.state, '"}')
  END) as map1,
```

If you want the additional filtering in the `CASE` expression, then add it to the conditions:

```
(CASE WHEN c.mainSubcategory = 216 AND c.id = ce.company_id
      THEN CONCAT('{"label":"map","link":"https://www.google.com/maps?q=', 
                  c.street_number, ' ',
                  c.city, ' ',
                  c.state, '"}'
                 )
      WHEN c.mainSubcategory = 217 AND c.id = ce.company_id
      THEN CONCAT('{"label":"map","link":"https://www.google.com/maps?q=', 
                  c.street_number, ' ',
                  c.city , ' ',
                  c.state, '"}')
  END) as map1,
```